# bs4 how to use find after using find_all?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to search a bbs and find the content of one specific user. Here is the code I have:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


main_html = requests.get('http://bbs.tianya.cn/post-free-2328897-1.shtml')
main_soup = BeautifulSoup(main_html.text, 'lxml')
all_a = main_soup.find_all('div', _host='羡鱼则结网')
```

Now I have all the code from this user and I would like to search again for the content. However, I can't use find because find_all returns a list. 
What should I do to search twice by BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Do you want to search in each item in the list? Then just iterate over it: `for a in all_a: ...`.

Comment: I recently had a similar problem where I used 2 for loops : 
for divs in all: 
    for div in divs:
        each item is represented by div you now use the attribute you want.

Comment: If this can help, this was the snippet of code I have used for my problem... note that it will not be working without tweaking:
`soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

content = soup.findChildren(class_='content-section')

for ptag in content:
    for i in ptag.findAll('p'):
        print(i.text.encode('utf-8'))`